# Selecting productid from a table that has at least 3 feedbacks greater than 3

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns (id, productID, and feedback) containing feedbacks:

```
id | productID     | feedback
.............................
1  | 1000          | 5
2  | 1000          | 4
3  | 1000          | 3
4  | 1001          | 5
5  | 1002          | 5
6  | 1002          | 5
7  | 1003          | 4
8  | 1003          | 5
9  | 1003          | 5
```

I would like to select a productID that has minimum 3 feedbacks and none of them has a value less than 4.
In this case, **1003** is the one that I would like to get.

Comment: Select where feedback>3 then group by productid and count(*)  then use having for the count >=3

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, updated the question, my question was not accurate.

Comment: See the answer from @tim

Comment: That throws Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: `select productid
from table
where feedback>3
group by prodcutid
having count(*)>=3`   I've not tested, but i will in a moment.

Comment: I have already tried your first comment out, but unfortunately it returns productID that has a feedback value of 3.

Comment: I see, you've changed your question. :o)

Comment: `select t.prodid,count(t.prodid) from table as t where not exists (select 1 from table as t2 where t2.prodid=t.prodid and t2.feedback<4) group by t.prodid having count(*)>=3`

Comment: This is it!!! Thank you. It works correctly.

Comment: Cool.  If you could mark the answer as correct to help others.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.prodid,count(t.prodid) from table as t 
where not exists 
(select 1 from table as t2 where t2.prodid=t.prodid and t2.feedback<4) 
group by t.prodid 
having count(*)>=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregation:

```sql
SELECT productID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY productID
HAVING SUM(feedback > 3) >= 3;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was not accurate. Edited the question. @Nathan_Sav's comment helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a MIN here to meet the requirement.

```
SELECT 
   productID
FROM 
   tableName
GROUP BY 
   productID
HAVING 
   MIN(feedback) >= 3;
```